# Connecting a display via USB-C

Tags: macos, multiple-monitors, hdmi, macos-monterey

Quick background:

- I'm on MacOS Monterey 12.4
- Macbook Pro 2021 M1

Problem:
Connecting a display via USB-C.

Details:

- I would like to connect two displays to my computer. One with the HDMI cable and one with either a USBC or a USBC -> HDMI adapter.
- Connecting either Disaplay with the HDMI port works flawlessly; however, connecting the external display with USB (with or wout adapeter) doesn't seem to get detected.
- The Cable does support video as well as the adapter works fine on another machine (and same monitor)

How can I troubleshoot this? I tried the majority of the apple support articles.

Precise specifications:
the model that I'm using is [this one](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP858?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US),
MacBook Pro (16-inch, 2021), on the official apple page, it reads:

> **Display Support**
>
> Simultaneously supports full native resolution on the built-in display
> at 1 billion colors and:
>
> - Up to two external displays with up to 6K resolution at 60Hz at over a
>   billion colors (M1 Pro) or

Comment: Are you sure your model supports two external monitors? I have read in a different question that the first M1 devices only support one external monitor.

Comment: It depends on the precise model - see https://everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/index-macbookpro.html [they don't seem to just label them by year any more]

Comment: I updated the question with more information regarding the model.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't specify which *exact* model you have, generally speaking the M1 MacBook Pros support two external monitors. Via the HDMI port and via *Thunderbolt* which uses a USB-C connector: https://www.apple.com/macbook-pro-14-and-16/specs/

Generally speaking you will need a display that supports Thunderbolt and purchase a cable that supports Thunderbolt.

`Note that USB-C is just **ONE** of the supported protocols and that you need a cable that supports Thunderbolt as well. So when purchasing a cable make sure it says that is supports Thunderbolt and not just USB-C.`

That said, you should be able to plug in two displays using the HDMI port on your Mac and one of the Thunderbolt ports. If you have a monitor that supports USB-C/Thunderbolt you just need a USB-C/Thunderbolt cable. If your monitor only has a DisplayPort or HDMI port then I would advise a cable with USB-C/Thunderbolt support on one end and the proper connector (HDMI or DisplayPort) on the other end.

While adaptors do generally work I have found that you get more consistent results with a single cable with no adapters. So your USB-C -> HDMI adapter *should be* fine as long as it supports Thunderbolt as well. But I would recommend a single cable with no adapters.